# Excel sort by (2 columns)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns in Excel

```
   A            B
name1        name4                 
name2        name3                 
name3        name1
name4                         
name5                        
name6
```

This is what the end result should be (for the column B), is it posibile?

```
   A            B
name1        name1                 
name2        
name3        name3
name4        name4                 
name5                        
name6
```

Thank you!

Comment: You do it by writing code.

Comment: To expand on @Jeeped remark, this is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. Start by taking the [2-minute tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `A` is in A1, insert a new ColumnB and populate B2 downwards with:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,C:C,1,0),"")
```

Comment: You are the best! Thanks!

Comment: @ kioreshima, please mark this question as solved by click the tick in pnuts answer. It shows that the question is solved and give the contributor the credit the person deserves :) take care